# Asus Ultrabook won't turn on

Tags: windows, laptop, battery, ultrabook

I have an [ASUS ZenBook UX31A](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ASUS-ZenBook-Touch-UX31A/) with Windows 8 installed on it. I recently tried to start the laptop, and it just doesn't do anything; it won't turn on any lights, no reaction whatsoever.

If I plug in my adapter the LED turns green (which means it's fully charged), but still it won't start, no matter what I do.

I've read that taking out the battery and waiting a bit can work, but that also can void the warranty. So preferably I won't do that if there are other solutions.

How can I start the computer?

Comment: Ok, it suddenly started, now updating bios, hoping this was the problem :)
EDIT: didn't work, back to trying to turn it on :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a loose connector in the computer, if you have the same problem of some keys stop working; just open it up and push the keyboard connector back in it's place :)